# I'm a lisp noobie, and I need a hash table class.

Tags: lisp, hashtable

I'm kind of new to lisp, and after coming from languages like C, Java, and Python, where there is a well defined set of standard libraries, I'm a little lost in the sea of implementations and libraries out there.

I'm looking for a few nice data structures to use as primitives, such as RB trees and dictionaries.

Comment: I fear you'll need to specify whether you use Scheme or Common Lisp, at the very least (propably also the specific implementation - I recall Scheme has no hashtable in the standard).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common Lisp has a specification: [CL HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm).

[Hash tables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_.htm) are part of that.

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp has some built-in data structures, like single-linked lists (also used for the language itself), arrays, and hash-tables.  There are lots of data structure libraries available from [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/releases.html), e.g. trees, spatial-trees, bk-tree.  Look at [CLiki's data structure directory](http://www.cliki.net/data%20structure) for some directions.

Answer (score 0):

[Common Lisp the Language, 2nd ed.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/cltl2.html), specifically [chapter 16: Hash Tables](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node154.html)

Comment: CLtL, 2ed is an interesting historical document. I would, preferentially, point people at the standard (or its web counterpart, the hyperspec).

Comment: @Vatine: HyperSpec is not the standard, nor it's web counterpart. It's a different document derived from the standard, although yes, it's probably the best source apart from the ANSI standard itself.

Comment: It is a hypertext document derived from the exact sources that the standard itself was prepared from. It is a darned bit closer to the standard than CLtL 2ed is.